# Could not resolve placeholder in string value

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use properties from a `.properties` file, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
@Service("ServiceFTP")
@Transactional
public class ServiceFTPImpl implements ServiceFTP {

    @Value("${project.ftp.adresse}")
    private String adresse;

    @Value("${project.ftp.login}")
    private String compte;

    @Value("${project.ftp.password}")
    private String motDePasse;

    @Value("${project.ftp.root}")
    private String ROOT;

    // [...]

}
```

This class uses `@Value` annotations to get the properties.
It is also declared as a Spring Service and is linked to my `infraContext.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:context-core.properties"/>

    <!-- [...]-->

</beans>
```

Using `context:property-placeholder`, I link this file to my `context-core.properties` file :

```
project.ftp.adresse = localhost
project.ftp.login = anonymous
project.ftp.password =
project.ftp.root = /anonymous/
```

This does make sense, right ?

But when I try to launch my project, Tomcat throw this exception:

```
ERROR [context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext()] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ServiceFTP': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String project.sins.service.impl.ServiceFTPImpl.adresse; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.ftp.adresse' in string value "${project.ftp.adresse}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1636)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String project.sins.service.impl.ServiceFTPImpl.adresse; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.ftp.adresse' in string value "${project.ftp.adresse}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.ftp.adresse' in string value "${project.ftp.adresse}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:151)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:748)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 29 more
```

Or, in short:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.ftp.adresse' in string value "${project.ftp.adresse}"

**Edit:**

Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="sins" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Project</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ExpiresByType text/html</param-name>
            <param-value>now plus 0 seconds</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ExpiresByType application/json</param-name>
            <param-value>now plus 0 seconds</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/tiles/user.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/si_nsg</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

My infraContext.xml is imported in another .xml file named applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="environment">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
        
    <import resource="classpath:securityContext.xml"/>

    [...]
    <import resource="classpath:project/sins/persistenceContext.xml"/>

    <import resource="classpath:project/sins/infraContext.xml"/>

</beans>
```

I am obviously missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Please let me know if you need more details, as it is my first question here.

I'll try to answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Where is your `infraContext.xml` being loaded? Judging from the stacktrace it isn't included in the configuration loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. Please post your web.xml.

Comment: Problem is you have multiple instances of a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` one explicitly defined (why?) and one due to the namespace. The one in your `applicationContext.xml` isn't doing anything nor adding anything. Remove it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In your configuration you have 2 `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instances.

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="environment">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

infraContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:context-core.properties"/>
```

By default a `PlaceholderConfigurer` is going to fail-fast, so if a placeholder cannot be resolved it will throw an exception. The instance from the `applicationContext.xml` file has no properties and as such will fail on all placeholders.

Solution: Remove the one from **applicationContext.xml** as it doesn't add anything it only breaks things.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, so I take it that in Spring that there can only be one instance of a `PlaceholderConfigurer` ?

Comment: No you can have multiple however by default they fail fast if a placeholder isn't found. You can disable this by setting `ignore-unresolved-placeholders` to `true`.

Comment: how I can handle it in spring boot with annotations ?

Answer (score 15):

I got same error in my Micro-service, whenever you declare @Value annotation in program i.e **@Value("${project.api.key}")**

make sure that your application.properties file with same values should not be blank **project.api.key= add some values**

**MostIMP** :otherwise it will throw error "Error creating bean with name 'ServiceFTP': Injection of autowired dependencies"

Comment: Make sure to update other profiles (dev, prod) as well.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue in the spring boot application.

When you add a property configuration to the application.properties file in main application SCR directory, make sure you do the same for application.properties file under the test directory.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try default values. [spring-value-annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Default values can be provided for properties that might not be defined. In this example the value “some default” will be injected:

```
@Value("${unknown.param:some default}")
private String someDefault;
```

If the same property is defined as a system property and in the properties file, then the system property would be applied.

Comment: Okay...this helped me. In fact my app has many application-<profile>.yml files, and I was receiving an error  due to a new property defined in the main config. file only. 
Honestly I was expecting to define the value only once in the main configuration, and in case override the value in a profile-specific configuration. 
Looks like it doesn't work like that, and a default value must be always provided. 
Now I understand why my java configurations were failing, when I didn't initialize properties with a default value! Can be this behaviour changed?  
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, resolved it by adding

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

in pom.xml :

before (didn't work):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>               
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

after(it worked):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

After that you just run *mvn clean install* and deploy application.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I'm curious though, why/how is the maven resources plugin affecting the spring placeholders... I never would have guessed they were related!

Comment: I had an extra line under <filtering> ... <excludes> which was causing the issue in my case, though nothing was being excluded.

Answer (score 5):

This Issue occurs if the application is unable to access the some_file_name.properties file.Make sure that the properties file is placed under resources folder in spring.

**Trouble shooting Steps**

1: Add the properties file under the resource folder.

2: If you don't have a resource folder. Create one by navigating new by Right click on the project new > Source Folder, name it as resource and place your properties file under it.

For annotation based Implementation

Add `@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:some_file_name.properties")`//Add it before using the place holder

Example:

Assignment1Controller.Java

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:assignment1.properties")
@RestController  
public class Assignment1Controller {

//  @Autowired
//  Assignment1Services assignment1Services;
    @Value("${app.title}")
    private String appTitle;
     @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")  
        public String getValues() {

          return appTitle;

        }  

}
```

assignment1.properties

```
app.title=Learning Spring
```

Comment: Does this apply to Spring4 and later ?

Comment: Yes @Malkocoglu

Comment: In my case application.yaml (can be application.properties) under test/resources shadowed the same file under main/resources - so my tests failed due to a missing variable in the former file.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was careless while merging the application.yml file, and I've unnecessary indented my properties to the right.

I've indented it like this:

```
spring:
    application:
       name: applicationName
............................
    myProperties:
       property1: property1value
```

While the code expected it to be like this:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: applicationName
.............................
myProperties:
    property1: property1value
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the same issue on running from eclipse. Just did the following to resolve it:
Right Click the Project --> Mavan --> Update Project.

And it worked!

Comment: This worked for me. I had no ident errors, but my program was giving an error which was solved after updating the project.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `<packaging>pom</packaging>` line in your pom.xml.

Comment: <packaging>jar</packaging> even this will work

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot :

In the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Example in class Java

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MyAppConfig {
    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;
    @Value("${bar}")
    private String bar;
    @Bean("foo")
    public String foo() {
        log.info("foo={}", foo);
        return foo;
    }
    @Bean("bar")
    public String bar() {
        log.info("bar={}", bar);
        return bar;
    }
    [ ... ]
```

In the properties files :

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
foo=all-env-foo
```

src/main/resources/application-rec.properties

```
bar=rec-bar
```

src/main/resources/application-prod.properties

```
bar=prod-bar
```

In the VM arguments of Application.java

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=[rec|prod]
```

**Don't forget to run mvn command after modifying the properties !**

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

In the log file for  -Dspring.profiles.active=rec :

```
The following profiles are active: rec
foo=all-env-foo
bar=rec-bar
```

In the log file for  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod :

```
The following profiles are active: prod
foo=all-env-foo
bar=prod-bar
```

In the log file for -Dspring.profiles.active=local :

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'bar' in value "${bar}"
```

Oups, I forget to create application-local.properties.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because the spring project doesn't read the file properties (**bootstrap.yml** or **application.yml**). In order to resolve this, you must add dependency in your **pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m frequently running into this issue on some custom properties that could not be found using **IntelliJ IDEA** - likely after **changing branches**.

What helpes in my case is

> **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**

I had the assumption that it is more likely a Gradle caching issue than an IDE issue, but **./gradle clean** did not help

Answer (score 1):

Adding same properties into application.properties would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I applied the same as Ben G and it worked for me. Try adding a space between $ and {

Comment: I fell for this fix at first but now I see it's nothing but a dirty workaround, and here's why. You can achieve the same effect by replacing the variable with a random string like this: @Value("$@#$%^&*()"). This will simply break your variable - so you don't get the error. As @Thisisalexis said under Ben G's response, "that's because the application is not looking for the property in any given properties file anymore, since you are not using the right syntax." So don't get deceived by the simplicity of this "fix" - it fixes nothihng.

Comment: This should be comment, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

I run into this when I created an `@Configuration` class with a prefix e.g. `foo.bar` then went ahead to attempt to autowire a property in another class using `@Value("${foo.bay.xyz}")`.

The solution was to add the `xyz` property to the configuration class and access it from an autowired bean of that class.

I could not find the reason for this in the docs but my guess is that spring was binding all properties under the `foo.bar` prefix under the configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my microservice project.The property itself missed in my yml file.So I added property name and value that resolves my problem

Answer (score 0):

I just added the configuration of the property in my `application.xml` file for my test folder, just the same way it is in my `SRC` folder and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Spring Boot with *spring-boot-starters* and you redefine variables in .yml / .properties file, make sure you using custom names for variables.
For example you're using spring-boot-starter-mail. And defining variables from mail-starter in the .yml file next way:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: ${my_smtp_host}
```

In this case you'll get an *`IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my_smtp_host' in string value "${my_smtp_host}"`*

To solve this issue just make custom variable. For example:

```
my-mail:
  host: ${my_smtp_host}
```

Another note - if you're using Openshift make sure your variable `my_smtp_host` not starting from digit:
change this -> `${123_my_smtp_host}`
to this -> `${my_smtp_host}`

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Idea "Invalidate Caches..." didn't work, but Gradle clean worked in my case.

Answer (score -5):

My solution was to add a space between the $ and the {.

For example:

```
@Value("${project.ftp.adresse}")
```

becomes

```
@Value("$ {project.ftp.adresse}")
```

Comment: no space should be required in there

Comment: I don't think that's a proper solution; of course it prevent the application to fail, but that's because the application is not looking for the property in any given properties file anymore, since you are not using the right syntax.