# Could not resolve placeholder in string value in elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get acess costume environment variable that I just added to Elastic beanstalk. The way i added the variable is only in Software Configuration.

The variable is FLAG and the value is 'true'.
In my code I'm doing this:

```
@Value("${FLAG}")
private Boolean flag1= true;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'FLAG' in string value "${FLAG}"
```

I'm working with java spring and AWS elastic beanstalk

Thank you

Comment: any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instances.

Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20245272/8800147

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Maybe it will sound weird and not make sense, but it works only after i turn off the Intellij and open again