# Eclipse: Could not resolve placeholder in string value

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse and I have turned on Build Automatically in Build Menu.

I have a Run Configuration like this.

It is pointing to ResourceServerApplication.java in Spring Boot App.

[image: debug configuration]

The problem is after I build the workspace then I try to run this DEBUG mode, there will be an error saying that 'Could not resolve placeholder in string value.'

Then I have to run the clean install command in Eclipse in order to make the above DEBUG mode work.

[image: clean install command]

Edit:

I have included multiple property file from multiple maven projects by using the below code in spring.xml.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/my-config1.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/my-config2.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

Comment: can you please add to your question your spring xml conf? thanks

Comment: @Leviand I have edit my question.

Comment: Look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244696/could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string-value , maybe it can help ! :)

Comment: @Leviand Seems like the post does not help.

Comment: what happens if you remove one of the 2 `property-placeholder` ?

Comment: @Leviand It is not working as I have other properties in another property file which is in use.