# Could not resolve placeholder 'version.v1' in value "/api/${version.v1}"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito

I am trying to write a Springboot end point unit test using Mockito. System failed to initialize the placeholder during test execution context. Could you please help me to understand where I am going wrong?

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MockLocationsController.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "version.v1=v1",    
    })
public class MockLocationsControllerTest {

}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'version.v1' in value "/api/${version.v1}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244696/could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string-value

Answer (score 0):

By providing a custom `@ContextConfiguration` you have created a limited Spring Test context which most likely doesn't have `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean. Without that bean property placeholders are not resolved.

Normally Spring Boot tests for the web layer with mocking are declared with [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) which gives you minimal working setup with `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig
@WebMvcTest(MockLocationsController.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "version.v1=v1",    
    })
public class MockLocationsControllerTest {

}
```

Comment: Thank you Karol, it didn't help  me